# A terrain with underground tunnels

Tags: unity, terrain, world-design

The Terrain tool in Unity is great for constructing 3-D landscapes that are open from above. I am working on a game that happens entirely inside tunnels (specifically, blood vessels in a human body. But it can also be tunnels in an ant nest, or sewers below a city). There is nothing "overground" - all movement is inside the tunnels. I am looking for a tool, similar to Terrain, for easily constructing this complex system of tunnels.

One solution I thought of is to construct a terrain with "half tunnels" (i.e., open from above), then duplicate it, rotate 180 degrees, and "glue" on top of the first copy. But it can only handle one layer of tunnels, and in addition, for some reason I could not rotate the terrain.

Is there a way to construct such underground tunnels with the Terrain tool, or with a different tool in Unity?

Answer (score -1):

I think, you can use something called Marching Cubes to make your own tunnel making tool. This video from Sebastian League should help you understand it quickly. It Explains how he used it to make his own tunnel making tool.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3iI2l0ltbE

Comment: This is a link only answer and provides no value if the link rots. Could you include the main points of the technique presented in the video in the answer itself, so that even without the link it would be valuable.